# How many images do I need to train a Deep Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, web-crawler, tensorflow, image-recognition

I am currently working on a small program that is trying to determine whether an apple is rotten or not. To start this off, I followed TensorFlow's MNIST tutorial which would identify a handwritten digit. From what I heard, MNIST contains 60,000 or so images to train my neural network. If I were to train my neural network to identify either 1 or 0, rotten or not, if an apple is rotten or not, how many images would I need in a csv to teach it? If I need over a thousand images, is there a way I can crawl through images from google to find what I need?

Comment: This is way too broad! The answer is so dependent on a lot of stuff you did not mention (architecture, image-characteristics and other stuff) and it's also a bit hard to answer in general theory-wise (a lot of empirical tests in practice). But yes: you would probably need thousands instead of hundreds (and probably many thousands). And using crawled images will suffer from label-noise and the problem of using partially-labeled data or noisy-labels is even much more complex than your core-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you could get away with less than 1000 images per class if you use Google's Inception classifier as a starting point. You can find a very gentle tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/cSKfRcEDGUs).